# JavaScript fetch API call with string interpolation with string contains # always null

Tags: javascript, fetch

If I pass a string as "testabc#" it breaks somewhere on the way route to the controller. I'm not sure why the # is causing me the issue. Is this a key work in JavaScript causing the issue? I have tried all other different specials characters and they work just fine. Has anyone else come across this issue.

```
`/api/Controller/UpdatePassword?currentPassword=${currentPassword.value}&newPassword=${newPassword.value}&confirmPassword=${confirmPassword.value}`,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor (#) is a feature of URL called fragment and it is used for internal page references. Using a question mark (?) and ampersand (&) can break your HTTP request like an anchor does because all of these things are URL features and it changes URL behavior.

To avoid this kind of error you must use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` like below:

with `encodeURIComponent()`:

```js
var url = `/api/Controller/UpdatePassword?currentPassword=${encodeURIComponent(currentPassword.value)}&newPassword=${encodeURIComponent(newPassword.value)}&confirmPassword=${encodeURIComponent(confirmPassword.value)}`
```

with `encodeURI()`:

```js
var url = encodeURI(`/api/Controller/UpdatePassword?currentPassword=${currentPassword.value}&newPassword=${newPassword.value}&confirmPassword=${confirmPassword.value}`)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that was an issue. I had to use encodeURICompment() thou in my case. Not sure entirely what is the difference currently.

Comment: My mistake, I corrected the answer sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

# in a url is a special character which indicates a "fragment", which means a special part of the url which is an anchor in the page, of sorts. Thats why it breaks your code. ? And & are also special, and so are a few others.

You should url encode data that you pass in the url.

Answer (score -1):

Try use `encodeURI()` to the url string before fetching, like:

```
var url = `/api/Controller/UpdatePassword?currentPassword=${currentPassword.value}&newPassword=${newPassword.value}&confirmPassword=${confirmPassword.value}`

encodeURI(url)
```